# Adding Controls with {binsreg}

Tags: r

I'm new to `{binsreg}` and am trying to get a grip on it. I'm hoping for some tips with issues I'm getting with adding controls.

```
library(binsreg)
library(tidyverse)



df<-tibble(x=runif(500), y=sin(x)+rnorm(500), 
           group = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 500, replace=TRUE), 
           gender = sample(c("M","F"), 500, replace=TRUE))

binsreg(df$y,df$x,w=df$gender)
#returns error
#Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(993L, 993L, 993L, 993L,  : 
#  replacement has 2000 rows, data has 500
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long way of saying I don't know, but it may be useful when you try to communicate with the package authors. I think there is some sort of bug in this new and apparently inadequately tested R package. I'm guessing that the authors are primarily Stata programmers and that it has been more thoroughly tested in that domain. If you run `traceback()` after getting the error you see a long output which I will provide in edited form:

```
traceback()
9: stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
       "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA)
8: `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 
   993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 
   993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 
   993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 
   993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 
   993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 
   993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 
snipped long output
   1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 
   1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 
   1000L, 1000L))
6: model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts)
5: model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
4: lm(y ~ P - 1, weights = weights)
3: binsregselect.rot(y, x, w, p, s, deriv, es = es, eN = eN, qrot = qrot, 
       norotnorm = norotnorm, weights = weights)
2: binsregselect(y, x, w, deriv = deriv, bins = dots, binspos = binspos, 
       binsmethod = binsmethod, nbinsrot = nbinsrot, vce = vce, 
       cluster = cluster, dfcheck = dfcheck, masspoints = masspoints, 
       weights = weights, numdist = Ndist.sel, numclust = Nclust.sel)
1: binsreg(df$y, df$x, w = df$gender)
```

Then when you try to find the function that calls `lm` and eventually throws the error you find that it is not exported but rather needs to be dug out of the namespace with `getAnywhere`:

```
getAnywhere(binsregselect.rot)
A single object matching ‘binsregselect.rot’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:binsreg
with value

function (y, x, w, p, s, deriv, es = F, eN, norotnorm = F, qrot = 2, 
    den.alpha = 0.975, weights = NULL) 
{
    x <- (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))
    ord <- p + 1
    N <- length(x)
    x.p <- matrix(NA, N, p + qrot + 1)
    for (j in 1:(p + qrot + 1)) x.p[, j] <- x^(j - 1)
    P <- cbind(x.p, w)
    est <- lm(y ~ P - 1, weights = weights)
```

So it appears that somewhere along the chain of function calls either `w` or `weights` has gotten a value other than NULL that constructs a model matrix that triggers this error. Or perhaps the default `qrot` value is constructing a malformed matrix, somehow? At any rate this is an error that was not picked up along the path of an extensive attempt at error detection efforts in these long functions. Suggest you execute:

```
maintainer('binsreg')  # and send an email with your compact example
```